# why tf.layers.batch_normalization works in inference mode only when is_training is true?

Tags: tensorflow

```
def _batch_norm(self, name, x, is_training=True):
 """Batch normalization.
  Considering the performance, we use batch_normalization in contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py
  instead of tf.nn.batch_normalization and set fused=True
  Args:
    x: input tensor
    is_training: Whether to return the output in training mode or in inference mode, use the argment
                 in finetune
 """
 with tf.variable_scope(name):
   return tf.layers.batch_normalization(
          inputs=x,
          axis=1 if self._data_format == 'NCHW' else 3,
          momentum = 0.997,
          epsilon = 1e-5,
          center=True,
          scale=True,
          training=is_training,
          fused=True
          )
```

This is my batch_norm code. when I am training the model, I will set the argument `is_training` with `True`, but when I want to inference the model, if I set it with `False`, it will output `wrong value`. However, if I set it with `True`, it will work in inference mode, Can anybody know why ?

Answer (score 0):

See the big blue "note" box at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization

You need to run the update ops (e.g. by passing them to your `Session`), or the moving mean/variance won't get updated and so will be incorrect for inference.

Comment: I have doubt about the parameter with the `training` and `trainable`, can you show a detail explain.

Comment: Agreed that this is a confusing distinction. `trainable` determines whether the variables are marked as trainable (and added to the trainable variables collection). That's beta and gamma. It won't switch the update ops on or off for the moving mean or moving variance, and it won't switch between using batch statistics and the moving statistics. Most people can just set `training` and forget about `trainable`.

Comment: so if we use the bn layer, the `training` and `trainable` must be same ?

Comment: I'd leave `trainable=True` and set `training` to `True` if you're optimizing (`False` otherwise).